# Apply multiple digital Signatures on PDF

Tags: php, pdf, digital-signature, tcpdf, fpdi

I have a project and i have to digitally sign a **PDF** more than once. I've tried to do this with **TCPDF**, but it seems that **TCPDF** allows only one Signature! because when I import the already signed PDF (with **FPDI**) and sign it, I have only the second sig. and the appearance (image) of the first one.

is that right?? or It's because **FPDI** didn't import the embedded signature?? and does **TCPDF** support incremental update??

1. is there a way that i can sign the same PDF twice with **TCPDF**??
2. or another Library that allows multiple signing with incremental updates??

Please any helpful Ideas or recommandations!

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

With FPDI you cannot edit an existing PDF document but you import the individual pages into a reusable structure. Content outside of a pages content stream (such as annotations or digital signatures) get lost.

Setasign (I'm related to that company), the authors of FPDI, also offers the [SetaPDF-Signer](https://www.setasign.com/signer/) component, which allows you to digital sign PDFs in pure PHP. The component is not free or open-source as FPDI.

See [here](https://manuals.setasign.com/setapdf-signer-manual/sign-several-times/) for how to sign a PDF document several times.

Comment: Hi. what is your competitor that is free?